# Java. Не работает полиморфизм для классов Exception

Tags: java, ооп, исключения

Столкнулся с феноменом:

```
public class MenuIndexException extends ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
    public MenuIndexException(String massage) {
        super(massage);
    }

    public void answer() {

    }
}
```

Почему не работает такая запись? Полиморфизм для классов исключений не работает? Или я как-то не правильно его применяю?

```
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex = new MenuIndexException("s");
ex.answer();
```

Не хочет компилироваться идея сразу подчеркивает красным... Почему?
хотя я и приравнял к указателю `ex = new MenuIndexException` у меня все равно нет метода который в этом классе находится...

Comment: А оно и не должно работать. Список доступных методов определяется по типу указателя.

Comment: А да вот оно что! А я думал по типу объекта все понятно спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Рабочий код решения:*

```
public class MenuIndexException extends ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -505311792750028191L;

    public MenuIndexException(String massage) {
        super(massage);
    }

    public void answer() {

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final MenuIndexException ex = new MenuIndexException("s");
        ex.answer();
    }
}
```